# c++ jump lines while debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm doing some coding in c++ and while debugging it jumps some lines, like constructors and many more. Someone have an idea how this could happen?

Here are the most important class declaration:

This is the declaration of the class for my GUI

```
#include "VisiTest.h"
#include "List.h"

class MonInterface : public VisiTest
{
public:
```

This is constructor where the skip line problem appears

```
MonInterface(char *theName);
public slots:
    virtual void testSuivant();
    virtual void demarrer();
    virtual void arreter();
    virtual void vider();
    virtual void premier();
    virtual void dernier();
    virtual void precedent();
    virtual void suivant();
private:
    Donnee donnee;
    List<Donnee> listDonnee;
    bool m_Started;
    int getIntCurrent();
};
```

This is the definition of the class's constructor

```
MonInterface::MonInterface(char * theName) : VisiTest(theName)
{
  donnee.typeTest = 0;
  donnee.registreSW = 0;
  donnee.retourSW = 0;

  donnee.registreLD = 0;
  donnee.valeurLD = 0;

  donnee.etatLD = 1;
  donnee.etatSW = 1;

  resetTest();
  resetArchive();
  m_Started = false;
}
```

Then in this constructor is skips many lines the object "donnee" contains many junk and my list too

Finally, this is the definition of the struct Donnee

```
struct Donnee
{
  int typeTest;

  int registreSW;
  int retourSW;
  int etatSW;

  int registreLD;
  int valeurLD;
  int etatLD;
};
```

Comment: Use the F11 (by default) key to step into functions, and make sure that that inlining is disabled.

Comment: Have you figure out how to solve this, please share solution with us

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile with some optimization level (-Ox)?
It happened to me when having optimization in gcc as well as debugging options.
If that is the case, removing of any optimization option will make your code to debug well.

Comment: i compiled with visual studio it's all automatically

Comment: Make shure you are debugging the Debug build, not the Release build. There is a quick access in a toolbar, or under the "Build" menu, select "Configuration Manager". The "Active solution configuration" should show "Debug" (that's in Visual Studio 2010, YMMV).